# Should I be transferring the AVPlayer or AVPlayerItem?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to continue the playing of a video without having to redownload it when I move to another view controller. Should I pass the `AVPlayer` as a reference, and add it to the playerLayer of my view, or should I pass the `AVPlayerItem` as a reference and add it to a fresh `AVPlayer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the same `AVPlayer` reference to the new `AVPlayerLayer`.
After passing your `AVPlayer` into new `AVPlayerLayer` make sure to destroy the old `AVPlayerLayer` (set it to nil).